# Windows 10 IoT wifi reconnect

Tags: raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I have thirty Raspberry 3 devices and Windows 10 IoT installed. These devices are connected to the access point with wifi. I gave each device a static IP. However, when the access point or router is restarted, the devices are not reconnected. But when I restart the devices, it connects.

Do you have a recommendation in this regard?

Comment: I have similar issues with you before, but I'm using Raspbian OS. I end up using a network status monitoring tool to reconnect the network.

Comment: You can check the same question [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5103dfcd-c4d8-47b0-8b2d-7249ddbdfe23/windows-10-iot-wifi-reconnect-problem?forum=WindowsIoT).